# Assign iterator to current element of std::vector in for each loop

Tags: c++, vector, foreach, iterator

I have a for each loop that loops through each element in a vector, and for each iteration of the loop I want to be able to begin an iterator that starts from the current element. I tried

```
// TypeVect is a std::vector of type Type
for (Type &element : TypeVect)
{
    std::vector<Type>::iterator it;
    it = &element;
    // ...
}
```

assuming that the iterator would be assigned to the address of the current element, but I am receiving the error:

> no operator = matches these operands ... Type *

I cannot figure out what the problem is. Any suggestions? I can handle my problem using indexing, but I am simply curious about this particular situation.

Comment: Why not just iterate through the container with iterators so you already have a iterator to the current element?

Comment: Maybe you should rethink your implementation, and use a "normal" iterator loop instead? Or rethink your design so you don't need iterators to begin with?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for your suggestion. That's how I'm going to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why range based loop syntax exists is that it simplifies trivial loops that iterate through the range/container/span exactly once.

Your intended loop is non-trivial. Writing that loop with the range based syntax would be more complicated than an old school index or iterator based loop. Which defeats the purpose of using a range based loop.

That said, if we allow ourselves to be silly, it is possible to get the iterator within a range based loop:

```
std::vector<Type>::iterator it = TypeVect.begin() + (&element - TypeVect.data());
```

> assuming that the iterator would be assigned to the address of the current element, but I am receiving the error "no operator = matches these operands ... Type *" and I cannot figure out what the problem is.

Your assumption is wrong. You cannot assign an address of an element to a variable of type `std::vector<Type>::iterator`. The problem is that the pointer is a different type than the iterator, and not convertible.

Comment: Okay it looks like my underlying assumption was wrong. I was using the for each loop to end up with "cleaner" looking code than indexing, but as someone pointed out above I can accomplish this using a for loop with iterators to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any other option than directly iterate over `iterator`

```
vector<Type> TypeVect;
// ...
for (vector<Type>::iterator it = TypeVect.begin() ; it != TypeVect.end() ; it++)
{
    Type & element = *it;
    // ...
}
```